# How do i refresh google token if expired?

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am Creating YouTube Broadcast and it successfully working.

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');

// $client->refreshToken($accessToken);
// // $client->refreshToken($accessToken);
// $newToken = $client->getAccessToken();
// echo "new token : ". $newToken;
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
try {



// Define service object for making API requests.
$service = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

// Define the $liveBroadcast object, which will be uploaded as the request body.
$liveBroadcast = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcast();


// Add 'contentDetails' object to the $liveBroadcast object.
$liveBroadcastContentDetails = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcastContentDetails();
$liveBroadcastContentDetails->setEnableClosedCaptions(true);
$liveBroadcastContentDetails->setEnableContentEncryption(true);
$liveBroadcastContentDetails->setEnableDvr(true);
$liveBroadcastContentDetails->setRecordFromStart(true);
$liveBroadcastContentDetails->setStartWithSlate(true);
$liveBroadcast->setContentDetails($liveBroadcastContentDetails);

// Add 'snippet' object to the $liveBroadcast object.
$liveBroadcastSnippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcastSnippet();
$liveBroadcastSnippet->setScheduledStartTime($start_date_time);
$liveBroadcastSnippet->setTitle($class_name);
$liveBroadcast->setSnippet($liveBroadcastSnippet);

// Add 'status' object to the $liveBroadcast object.
$liveBroadcastStatus = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcastStatus();
$liveBroadcastStatus->setPrivacyStatus('unlisted');
$liveBroadcast->setStatus($liveBroadcastStatus);


$response = $service->liveBroadcasts->insert('snippet,contentDetails,status', $liveBroadcast);
return ($response->id);


} catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
print_r($e);
} catch (Google_Exception $e) {
print_r($e);
}
```

but after some time Authorization failed.
token has been expired and unable to create broadcast.
I tried to refresh token but not working please help.

[https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/insert?apix=true[][1]](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/insert?apix=true%5B%5D%5B1%5D)

Answer (score 0):

First make sure to request offline access this will return a refresh token to you

```
function buildClient(){
    
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAccessType("offline");        // offline access.  Will result in a refresh token
    $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
    $client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/client_secrets.json');
    $client->addScope([YOUR SCOPES HERE]);
    return $client;
}
```

The first time the user authorizes you should have a refresh token in returned. Store it some place.

```
$client->getRefreshToken()
```

Make sure that you load the refresh token inside the $client->setRefreshtoken($stored) so that it has it for the next part.

Then check if the access token has expired and add the refresh token back and force a fetch of a new access token.

```
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {              
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
            $client->setAccessToken($client->getAccessToken()); 
}
```